# Slightly different behavior than ScreenSpaceGroup3D

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using a ScreenSpceGroup3D class in sharpDX for my model because I need independent from zoom always the same size. Independent from change the camera position the model is always visible (rotation graphic).

What can I do if another model is in the foreground that the ScreenSpaceGroup3D disappears?

I tried to solve my problem with the ScreenSpaceGroup3D. It did not lead to the desired result

Comment: It is not really clear what you have done or what your desired result is. Some example code and/or image example would probably help. I have very limited experience with SharpDX, but my understanding is that it is not compatible with WPF 3D. Your question is also littered with spelling and grammatical errors, this especially matters when referring to specific classes. Google has zero hits for "ScreenSpceGroup3D", so I have no idea what specific class you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I try again:

The Class what I use is ScreenSpacedGroup3D (it is a helix class).

I need to show a figure that always stays the same size when grafic will be zoomed. This behavior offers me the ScreenSpacedGroup3D.
If another model moves in front of the position of the ScreenSpaceGroup3D models, the ScreenSpaceGroup3D model should be hidden (like Leyer).
This is what I need.

Comment: It's not possible since they are rendered by different cameras and depth values are not correlated.